# Mosync compile on linux fails

Tags: c++, mobile, compilation, mosync

I am trying to compile MoSync, but get the following errors.
I looked around on the mosync forum but couldn't find anything...

```
$ ./workfile.rb CONFIG="debug"

Hook directories are equal.
Set constant "CONFIG"="debug"
/home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/intlibs/idl-common []
get_gcc_version_string(gcc)
GCC version: "4.6.1"
GCC_IS_V4: true
GCC sub-version: 6
/home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/intlibs/filelist []
/home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/tools/idl2 ["compile"]
/home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/intlibs/profiledb []
/home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/intlibs/helpers/platforms/linux []
/home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/intlibs/bluetooth []
In /home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/intlibs/bluetooth
Because file does not exist:
Execute: build/debug/bluetoothbluez.o
gcc -o "build/debug/bluetoothbluez.o" -std=gnu++0x -DHAVE_TR1 -fno-rtti -g -O0 -fvisibility=hidden -I "/home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/runtimes/cpp/base" -I "/home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/runtimes/cpp/platforms/sdl" -I "/home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/intlibs" -I "/home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/libs" -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wundef -Wfloat-equal -Winit-self -Wmissing-noreturn -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wvariadic-macros -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wmissing-declarations -Wvla -Wlogical-op -DBLUEZ_SUPPORTED -DLINUX -fPIC -MMD -MF "build/debug/bluetoothbluez.mft" -c "/home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/intlibs/bluetooth/linux/bluez/bluetoothbluez.cpp"
In file included from /home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/intlibs/bluetooth/linux/bluez/bluetoothbluez.hpp:29:0,
                 from /home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/intlibs/bluetooth/linux/bluez/bluetoothbluez.cpp:35:
/home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/intlibs/bluetooth/linux/bluez/cbtdevice.hpp: In constructor ‘CBtDevice::CBtDevice(const MABtAddr*, const char*)’:
/home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/intlibs/bluetooth/linux/bluez/cbtdevice.hpp:56:34: error: converting to non-pointer type ‘char’ from NULL [-Werror=conversion-null]
/home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/intlibs/bluetooth/linux/bluez/bluetoothbluez.cpp: In member function ‘void Bluetooth::BlueZ::BluetoothBluez::discoverDevices(Bluetooth::MABtCallback, bool)’:
/home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/intlibs/bluetooth/linux/bluez/bluetoothbluez.cpp:470:26: error: converting to non-pointer type ‘char’ from NULL [-Werror=conversion-null]
/home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/intlibs/bluetooth/linux/bluez/bluetoothbluez.cpp:476:71: error: passing NULL to non-pointer argument 5 of ‘int hci_read_remote_name(int, const bdaddr_t*, int, char*, int)’ [-Werror=conversion-null]
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors

Error: Command failed, code 1
/home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/rules/error.rb:19:in `error': Command failed, code 1 (RuntimeError)
    from /home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/rules/util.rb:101:in `sh'
    from /home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/rules/util.rb:92:in `popen'
    from /home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/rules/util.rb:92:in `sh'
    from /home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/rules/gcc.rb:81:in `execute'
    from /home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/rules/task.rb:199:in `invoke'
    from /home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/rules/task.rb:244:in `invoke'
    from /home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/rules/task.rb:196:in `invoke'
    from /home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/rules/task.rb:196:in `each'
    from /home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/rules/task.rb:196:in `invoke'
    from /home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/rules/task.rb:244:in `invoke'
    from /home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/rules/task.rb:85:in `invoke'
    from /home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/rules/task.rb:85:in `each'
    from /home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/rules/task.rb:85:in `invoke'
    from /home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/intlibs/bluetooth/workfile.rb:44
    from /home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/rules/task.rb:138:in `load'
    from /home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/rules/task.rb:138:in `invoke_subdir_ex'
    from /home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/rules/task.rb:147:in `invoke_subdirs_ex'
    from /home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/rules/task.rb:147:in `each'
    from /home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/rules/task.rb:147:in `invoke_subdirs_ex'
    from /home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/rules/task.rb:144:in `invoke_subdirs'
    from ./workfile.rb:115
    from /home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/rules/targets.rb:35:in `call'
    from /home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/rules/targets.rb:35:in `invoke'
    from /home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/rules/targets.rb:122:in `invoke'
    from /home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/rules/targets.rb:118:in `each'
    from /home/elijah/code/MoSync/mosync_trunk/rules/targets.rb:118:in `invoke'
    from ./workfile.rb:190
```

Does anyone know why these errors are happening?

P.S. The moSync image/audio capcha is broken for linux atm, that is why I am posing here instead...

EDIT: The moSync image/audio capcha is completely broken for all platforms.. gah.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you first compile the mosync "gcc" branch. and then compile the mosync sdk.
see here: http://www.mosync.com/documentation/manualpages/building-mosync-source-linux

I use the https://github.com/fredrikeldh/MoSync-gcc3 for gcc and https://github.com/fredrikeldh/MoSync for mosync sdk. successfully compiled in ubuntu 12.04 x86_64.

remember to see the linux.txt on docs:

These packages are required to build MoSync on Xubuntu 11.10:

## 1.9 might work, but no guarantees.

ruby1.8

g++
libsdl1.2-dev
libbluetooth-dev
libssl-dev
libexpat1-dev

## libglew1.5-dev should also work.

libglew1.6-dev

libgtk2.0-dev
libsdl-image1.2-dev
libsdl-ttf2.0-dev
libfreeimage-dev

## for pipe-tool. appears to be available/needed only on Ubuntu 11.04 and below.

libc6-dev-i386
lib32z1-dev

gperf